# NodeJS - How to resolve “Cannot find module” error on local modules?

Tags: node.js, npm

I'am aware the best npm install is to use `npm install`, but it is forbidden on the professional server I use. Also,I must install my node_modules via a dirty `git clone <node_module_git_repository>`.

Via git, my modules are copied well and runs fine via :

```
node ./node_modules/.bin/http-server
```

But fail via :

```
node http-server
```

I get back the error:

```
module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module '/data/yug/projects_active/make-modules/http-server'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:935:3
```

I assume that not doing npm install make that my node modules are not in path. **How could I fix that to my git-cloned local modules runs via `node <module_name>` ?**

Comment: `./node_modules/.bin/http-server` doesn't seem right to me. It normally has the package name in the path. For example, `./node_modules/http-server/.bin/http-server`

Comment: Both `./node_modules/.bin/http-server` and `./node_modules/http-server/.bin/http-server`  works for me. But no `http-server` doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The incantation you are asking about won't work. The `node` executable expects a path to a javascript file to execute. The path can be relative to the current working directory or absolute, but that's it. It does not search `node_modules` or NODE_PATH like `require` does from within a node.js program.

When you run `./node_modules/.bin/http-server` your shell is executing that file, which starts with a shebang line something like `#!/usr/bin/env node` which handles running node and passing it the path to the `http-server` file for you.

If you are set on wanting `node http-server` to work, create a symlink in the make-modules directory: `cd make-modules && ln -nsf ./node_modules/.bin/http-server`.